# Is it possible for a non-lord to take a lord hostage?

Tags: mount-and-blade-with-fire-and-sword

The King of Sweden went missing.

None of the other lords knows where the heck he is.  I've gone and scouted every town and castle of the enemy faction and did not see him in any of the jails.  I've also scouted as many enemy lords as I can find and did not see him there either.

The only thing left I can think of is if he went and lost to some stupid bandits or enemy scouts and they're dragging him around somewhere.  Is this possible?

Comment: Börk Börk Börk!

Comment: @DoozerBlake its entirely possible he's off cooking somewhere :P

Comment: I'm not sure about wfas, but in warband native, a Lord need some time after being freed to come back. Although, if you had time to go to every jail in the world, he should be back already.

Comment: @Jupotter its been 30 elapsed game days and he still hasn't shown up yet so I'm chalking this up as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a [bug](http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?topic=185653.00) and I guess it hasn't been fixed yet since the version I have is the latest.