# How to locate imprisoned lord to rescue him

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I've been trying to locate a lord (Count Matheas) that has been imprisoned for around a month. I went through all the castles and cities of the faction that is detainning him but I cannot find him anywhere.

How can I locate him so I can rescue him? Can I talk to a NPC that is able to tell me where he is or could be?

Comment: This might be a glitch.  I've seen posts on forums before where lords just disappeared (happened to me in [fire and sword with the king of sweden](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65047/is-it-possible-for-a-non-lord-to-take-a-lord-hostage)).  A month is a long time usually they escape or get released by then.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is super old, but best way to locate an imprisoned lord to rescue is follows:

1. Under “notes”, go to character, find the lord in question
2. Find a relative, who is also a lord (father, son, etc)
3. Locate that relative lord, and then ask for a task.
4. My first attempt, got a “rescue my son from prison” quest, which of course tells you exactly where he is.

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 1):

He might be with some of the other faction party, the best way to find him is probably go fight some of the other faction parties if you win against the one that has him as a hostage you can free him

Comment: Well, he spent more than 20 days as a prisoner. Wont he be moved in a town instead of staying in a party? Logic wants that it would be safer and would actually make sense.

Comment: http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/958942-mount-and-blade-warband/answers?qid=190141 Here is a link i found about it, you need to find the town that he is and talk to the prison guard first, then talk to the lord

Comment: My problem is that I went through all the towns and I couldnt find him. I want to know if there is another way of finding which town he is in.